# Google Sheets - Autoreplace a value when a new row is created

Tags: google-sheets, automation, zapier

I use Zapier to create a new row in a Google Sheet doc for each new registration on our website. However, I want to autoreplace a value of a cell when the row is created or, if it's not possible, using a script with onOpen, or any time-based trigger.

Here is an example of the data that needs to be changed in two specific columns (say, A and C)...

```
/*Job - Column A - English to French*/
 'Management':'Gestion',
 'Social work':'Travail social',
 'Reception':'Accueil',
 'Art Therapy':'Art-thérapie',
 'Volunteer work':'Bénévole',

/*Workplace - Column C - English to French*/
'Starting Community':'Communauté en démarrage',
'CLAN Program' : 'Programme FER',
'Other (specify)' : 'Autre affiliation',
'University (specify)' : 'Université',
```

How can I do that? I managed to use an onEdit trigger, but since it can't be activated by Zapier, it's useless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** achieve this behavior with an `Edit` trigger in Apps Script.

Zapier will edit the Spreadsheet via API call and this is actually one of the trigger limitations:

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

You should probably craft this auto-replace feature in the Zapier environment directly.

Refer to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) for additional Apps Script triggers limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is it possible to trigger autoreplace automaticly at the opening of the document (via onOpen maybe?) ?

Comment: Sure you can use that as a workaround. I edited my answer since it wasn't really clear on that point. I'm sorry if it caused confusion.

Comment: The issue is, it does not work using onOpen. Is there anything I need to change in the code to make it work?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the onOpen function you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I use for having automatic functions applied on the row created in a Google Sheet by Zapier is by doing the automation with Google Sheet functions. Your document should have **3 tabs**:

1. Where Zapier will create new rows
2. On this tab, you will use the **IMPORTRANGE** function (to import all the data from the **tab1**).
3. Where you can do your magic (functions doing exactly what you want, using reference to the cells of the **tab2**).

Optionally, you can then hide the first 2 tabs, once your setup is complete on the **tab3**.